Pourquoi intimé signifie-t-il « défendeur en appel » ?

Intimé : Personne qui réagit ou qui est partie adverse à une requête faite par un requérant; aussi une personne qui réagit ou qui est partie adverse à un appel interjeté par un appelant. (Respondent)


L'intimé est la personne qui est convoquée en appel. Elle ne conteste pas la décision de justice rendue. Elle reçoit une requête d'appel introduite par une autre partie au procès, qui, elle, conteste la décision.


Défendeur en appel (opposé à appelant)

En 1412, « intimé   » provient « "du participe passé de intimer ». Mais qu'y a-t-il d'intime dans le fait d'être un intimé ?
Mais est-il contradictoire, paradoxal  que  « intimé  » signifie défendeur dans une cause en appel ? Le litige n'est pas de tout intime au sens amical, romantique ou sensuel ! Le litige est le contraire de « intime ! Le litige entraîne l'iatrogenèse légale, des dommages critogènes, et des coûts « psychologiques » découlant de la décision d’engager des poursuites.

@Kamala-1FTW Entièrement d'accord avec toi, si pour tout francophone c'est évident qu'il n'y a pas de rapport entre l'adjectif intime et le verbe intimer, je comprends qu'un non francophone puisse faire le rapprochement. Moi non plus je ne trouve pas cette information dans un dictionnaire standard, j'en ai consulté plusieurs.

Bien qu'en remontant au latin classique on puisse trouver un rapport étymologique entre l'adjectif intime et le verbe intimer (et ses dérivés), tout rapport lexical entre les deux mots était déjà perdu en ancien français. Je pense qu'aucun francophone (sauf peut-être latinisant, et encore !) ne ferait de rapprochement entre le fait d'être intimé en justice et une quelconque intimité.
En latin classique on trouve intimus, superlatif de interior : ce qui est le plus profond en dedans, le plus intérieur.   L'adjectif intime est directement emprunté (1376-1377) de intimus et signifie de nos jours :

Qui se situe ou se rattache à un niveau très profond de la vie psychique; qui reste généralement caché sous les apparences, impénétrable à l'observation externe, parfois aussi à l'analyse du sujet même.
[...]
Qui constitue fondamentalement les caractères propres de tel individu, sa nature essentielle; qui se rattache à ce qu'il y a de plus personnel en lui. [...]
(TLF)

En bas latin on trouve intimo (intimare), issu du latin classique intimus avec le sens de annoncer, publier, faire savoir1 et qui a donné le français (1325) intimer :

« avertir (qqn.) de qqch., faire savoir »
(Dictionnaire historique de la langue française2).

et dont le sens a évolué (1332) en  :

« signifier, déclarer avec autorité » et en droit « signifier légalement ».
Le dérivé intimé, ée. adj. et n., terme de droit, apparait comme adjectif 1412) dans partie  intimée « assignée en justice » puis come substantif (1460-1466) pour désigner le défendeur en appel, emploi typique de la langue classique (cf. l'Intimé, personnage des Plaideurs de Racine)
(Dictionnaire historique de la langue française2).

À propos du verbe intimer on peut noter que de nos jours il est largement employé en dehors du domaine juridique pour signifier « donner un ordre de façon autoritaire ».

1 C'est à dire exposer quelque chose qu'on a en soi et que les autres ne connaissent pas. (Mon interprétation).
2 Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, sld Alain Rey.

Merci! :-) Très bonne réponse au fait.

I'm being told I don't answer the question of why it means that. So I ask you: Do you explicitly say why it does? Or does your answer trace the history of its appearance in thee language? (Which iis fine with me by the way). :)

@Lambie It seems we have different interpretations of the question. To me the crux of the question is "Mais qu'y a-t-il d'intime dans le fait d'être un intimé ?" The OP knows what intimé means: they give a synonym in the title of the question and start the question by giving a definition, they even mention it is the pp of the verb intimer, but they think the adjective intime and the verb  intimer are words of the same family and try to make a connection between being intimate (intime) and being summoned (intimé). My aim in my answer was to disambiguate this connection.

@Lambie "Do you explicitly say why it does? " It seems it is very explicit in my quote of the DHLF (apparently others members of FL are of the same mind), intimé means la personne qui est convoquée en appel, Défendeur en appel (opposé à appelant), because of its Latin root and the way the meaning has evolved.

Ah, right. I do see what you mean now. The fact the two words don't have the same root. I missed the last sentence in the question. Thanks for your answer to my question. And for the record, I did not vote to close this question. Or dv this answer.

@Lambie "To me the crux of the question is "Mais qu'y a-t-il d'intime dans le fait d'être un intimé ?" Je suis d'accord avec None.

La raison est juridique:

Définition de Intimé en partenariat avec Baumann Avocats Droit informatique
Dans le langage de la procédure judiciaire, l' "intimé"
est le mot par lequel est désigné le défendeur à l'instance d'appel.
L'intimé auquel le tribunal n'a pas reconnu l'ensemble des prétentions
qu'il a fait valoir devant cette juridiction, peut saisir la Cour d'
un appel incident. Il peut être formé en tout état de cause. Cette
voie de réformation est recevable bien que, le jugement de première
instance ayant été signifié à l'intéressé, l'auteur de l'appel
incident ne serait plus dans les délai pour faire un appel principal.
Dans ce cas, s'agissant d'une procédure liée à l' appel principal, la
recevabilité de l'appel incident reste subordonnée à la validité de
l'appel principal.


Définition de Appelant en partenariat avec Baumann Avocats Droit
informatique
Le mot "appelant" désigne le plaideur qui estimant ne
pas avoir été rempli de ses droits par le jugement rendu en premier
ressort, prend l'initiative de saisir la Cour d'appel d'un recours.
L'adversaire de l'appelant qui est attrait devant la Cour d'appel est
dénommé l'"intimé".

Dictionnaire du droit privé
par Serge Braudo
Conseiller honoraire à la Cour d'appel de Versailles
dictionnaire juridique 

Tu ne réponds pas à la question du pourquoi.

@Frank  Parce que c'est une apparition.  (reponse de none) [[comm Le dérivé intimé, ée. adj. et n., terme de droit, apparait comme adjectif 1412) dans partie  intimée « assignée en justice » puis come substantif (1460-1466) pour désigner le défendeur en appel]],

Oui, None répond à la question du pourquoi. Mais dans ta réponse, je ne vois qu'une définition, que l'OP connaissait déjà, puisque cette définition était dans le titre même de la question...

@Frank Come on, the answer only says the meaning appeared and evolved. It  does not say "why it means that".

L'étymologie depuis le latin est expliquée, qui aura bien valeur de réponse au pourquoi.

@Lambie Mais je demande, et voudrais savoir, "why it means that".
